# Complex Linq Query on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a linq query, to get all Modules with the Forms of each Module depending on the rights of the current user, so i can build up my program menu on the users log on.

What is the most efficient way to get the result in a single linq query from the following database structure? [image: the following database structure?]
So I can do the following with the query result:

```
foreach (var module in PermittedModuls)
{
   //do some stuff
   .....


   foreach(var form in module.Forms)
   {
     //do some stuff
     .....
   }
}
```

I already got some "dirty" solutions to get it, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

By the way I'm using Entity Framework 6

EDIT!!!: Sorry guys, i think my question was not clear.

I wand to get only the forms where the user has a permission!!!

Comment: You said you had a couple of dirty solutions. Show those so we can offer improvements.

Comment: Rather than showing your DB model, show your EF model

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details about how you plan on filtering the data, you could simplify your code to

```
var forms = PermittedModules.SelectMany(x => x.Forms);
```

This would give you all the forms on every module (presuming that's what you want).

Comment: This doesn't allow him to do something for each item in `PermittedModuls`, which is a part of his requirements.

Comment: @Servy where does it say that? The OP asked *"I'm trying to build a linq query, to get all Modules with the Forms of each Module depending on the rights of the current user...what is the most efficient way to get the result in a single LINQ query"*.

Comment: So that he can do what he described in the given code snippet. He has shown that he's doing something with `module` besides just getting the forms.  Your code doesn't allow for that.

Comment: @Servy his code doesn't show that at all, your assuming that `// do some stuff` means he is using `module` when in fact it can mean *anything*.

Comment: His code shows *exactly* that, assuming that `//do some stuff` means anything other than "do nothing".  Given this query how do you plan to execute that code for each module?

Comment: @Servy no it doesn't, `// do some stuff` could be doing some setup for the `Form` - you have no idea what it does so, again, I reiterate you are assuming.

Comment: Okay, so assuming it's doing some setup for the form, where, in your query, do you plan to perform such setup?  You're assuming it does exactly nothing, because if it's doing anything else then your query can't do it.  I'm assuming that `//do some stuff` means that he wants to do some stuff.  Seems like a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: Sorry guys, i think my question was not clear.

I wand to get only the forms where the user has a permission!!!

Comment: @Servy I don't because I am not interested in that, my answer is geared towards the actual question and not speculating on what a comment means...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code *basically* does what you want, except that you want to indicate that `Forms` should be eagerly populated for each item when you execute the original query, rather than lazily performing N round trips to get each of the modules' forms data.  To do this, you use `Include`:

```
foreach (var module in PermittedModuls.Include(m => m.Forms))
{
   //do some stuff

   foreach(var form in module.Forms)
   {
     //do some stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: the include is not the problem, i want just to get the forms that are permitted to be seen by the user, depending on his permissions

Comment: @user3041845 So you're saying that the question that you asked has nothing to do with what you want?  Your question mentions nothing at all about permissions.

Comment: @Seivy **depending on the rights of the current user**